# Adding a rowfilter to my datagridview (Unbound datasource)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, rowfilter

I am trying to add a row filter to my datagridview, however I do not have a datasource. How can I add my (already existing data) to a datasource?

```
        For Each th As HtmlElement In tHeaders
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.HeaderText = th.InnerText})
        Next

            For i = 2 To tRows.Count - 1
                Dim r As New DataGridViewRow
                For Each td As HtmlElement In tRows(i).GetElementsByTagName("td")
                    r.Cells.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxCell With {.Value = td.InnerText})
                Next
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(r)
        Next
```

I do know how to use the rowfilter function, but for that to work I believe I require a datasource. If I am mistaking I would like to know :)

Comment: Please provide details on filtering e.g. on a specific column, all rows and cells etc.

Comment: I am having 4 columns and I would like to filter on column index 0 (so my first column). there are like 100 rows in my datagridview. The datagrid is grabbed from a website table and it will automaticly put it in the dgv. Unfortuatly I am new to bindingsources and datatable / gridviews.